# Unable to detect end of web page scrolling in Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have some JS/jQuery code on my page that is supposed to perform an action once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.  Here's the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (position >= $(document).height()) {
        // bottom is hit, do something
    }
});
```

This works just fine in several browsers that I've tested:

- Chrome for Mac
- Firefox for Mac
- Safari for iOS
- Firefox for Android

The only one that it doesn't work on is Chrome for Android.  It's been an issue for at least a little while, but currently on Chrome Android version 57.0.2987.132.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Sad to say, I still haven't.  I'm planning on coming back around to this problem shortly, so I'll repost if I happen to find a solution.

Comment: ```more than a year later``` i am experiencing the same issue.
please post an answer if is is resolved

Comment: ok i got it, the workaround for me is, instead of using ```$(window).height()```
i use ```$(myFooterElement).offset().top```

Comment: still not working for me. there's some sort of bug that makes it work after switching tabs or closing and reopening chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

```
if (position >= $(document).height()) {
    // bottom is hit, do something
});
```

should be

```
if (position >= $(document).height()) {
    // bottom is hit, do something
}
```

without the `);` at the end.

Otherwise, your logic is fine, I tested it in Chrome for desktop as well as for Android.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Bad copy/pasting on my part :)  What version of chrome are you running on android?

Comment: It's actually older than yours, 55.0.2883.91 . Can you try to isolate this functionality and test it independently on Android? Just to remove the possibility of other code from its context interfering with it.

Comment: If the provided answer solves the issue, consider clicking the (arrow up) icon that means, the answer is useful. This is just one of the many cool features of the community that we should not neglect.